# Refillable Java queue

Tags: java, queue

Is there any open source implementation of a "refillable" queue in Java?

Essentially, such a queue would be implemented as a class which reads data from a source and stores it in its memory buffer, which is replenished every time the queue capacity falls below a predefined threshold. Therefore, it requires:

1. An in memory buffer to hold the data.
2. An input source to fill the buffer whenever it goes below threshold.

JMS queues or any other messaging system which uses network serialization are not suitable, for performance reasons.

The scenario is trivial and easy to implement, but if there is a library that offers this functionality already, there is no need to reinvent it.

Comment: Well. I dont know an exact class, but Google Guava may be worth a look.

Comment: Many messaging systems have something like this built in. Which queue are you using?  Note: TCP sockets are already a queue.

Comment: I have used JMS queuing systems quite a bit and they are not suitable for the described use case, for performance reasons. So, an in-memory queue is what is needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[`RabbitMQ`](https://www.rabbitmq.com) is a message broker. In essence, it accepts messages from producers, and delivers them to consumers. In-between, it can route, buffer, and persist the messages and data according to rules you give it.

You can also use [Google Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/Release16)

Comment: JMS systems (or any other implementation that uses the network) are not suitable for this use case. Guava does not seem to have anything useful, either. Thanks though and +1. :-)